# Is there a way to delete components from an array with a button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Still pretty new to react, so sorry if this question seems very simple.

I'm currently having issues where I have a component that I am attempting to add in each time the add button is clicked (which works) but when I press the delete button, it deletes all of the components in the array except the first one which cannot seem to be deleted. I am using .splice() to attempt to remove the last element in the array (-1) and setting the new state to reflect that but everything I do doesn't seem to fix anything. Any input would be greatly appreciated!

```
function App() {
  const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([]);
  const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(false);

  const onAddBtnClick = event => {
    if (inputList.length < 5){
      setInputList(inputList.concat(<Autocomplete items={universities} />));
    }else{
      setDisabled(true);
    }
  };

  const onDeleteBtnClick = event => {
    setInputList(inputList.splice(-1, 1));
    if (inputList.length < 5){
      setDisabled(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div className="autocompleter">
        <Button onClick={onAddBtnClick} disabled={disabled} size="lg" block>Add Education (Maximum 5)</Button> 
        <Button onClick={onDeleteBtnClick} size="lg" block>Delete Education</Button> 
        {inputList}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't be using `splice` anyways, try `slice(0,-1)` instead

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the last element use Array.splice(0,array.length-1). This will remove your last element. Hope this helps. In your case use this block of code.

```
setInputList(prev=>prev.splice(0,prev.length-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that splice doesn't return a new object, it returns the deleted elements. So you are setting the wrong new state.

Take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), you could use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) instead